# Is it feasible to build jdk for alpine from ubuntu?

Tags: java

Is it feasible to build jdk for alpine from ubuntu?

I built [jdk11](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/tree/jdk-11+19) from ubuntu and then upload the build to my alpine.

However, alpine keeps saying `./java: not found`

how do I do?

[image]

Comment: This symptom looks like a mismatch in `ld.so`. Run `file ./java`, look for "interpreter". This is probably different between the two distros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it feasible to build jdk for Alpine from Ubuntu?

Firstly, it is clearly feasible to build OpenJDK for Alpine, because there are examples of Alpine Docker containers for OpenJDK.

Cross-compiling on Ubuntu for Alpine should also work.  But there is a caveat in the OpenJDK Build instructions:

> "It is often not much problem to build OpenJDK on Linux. The only general advice is to try to use the compilers, external libraries and header files as provided by your distribution."

If you are having problems getting the Java executables you built on Ubuntu to work you could try:

- building on Alpine itself, or
- installing the Alpine headers and libraries on your Ubuntu box and using them in your build rather than the Ubuntu headers and libraries.

If you are cross compiling using the Alpine headers etc, you should also read the corresponding section on the build instructions.   And read about the `--with-sysroot=...` configuration option.

(It would help if you already have a good understanding of how C / C++ compilation works, and experience with using the gcc and configure tool-chains.  The OpenJDK build instructions assume this.)

Answer (score 0):

There are ready images with Liberica JDK for Alpine for various architectures and versions https://hub.docker.com/r/bellsoft/liberica-openjdk-alpine-musl, so you don't have to go to all the trouble of building the JDK yourself.